# VBA; Lookup multiple instances of a variable and copy range to another sheet

Tags: vba, match, lookup

I currently have a spreadsheet tab containing amounts to be paid by various clients.  Often there is more than one row per client.  What I need to do is be able to select all the instances of this client, then copy all the columns of data for each instance of the client into another tab.  At the moment I only know how to select the first instance of the record.

So For Example, I want to put all instances of Client with ID 1 into another tab;

Data Tab

ID Amt

1  £20

2  £10

3  £15

1  £10

2  £20

Invoice Tab

ID Amt

1  £20

1  £10

I hope I've explained this well enough, but please let me know if you need more detail.
I'm pretty new to VBA so sorry if this is actually a very easy question.

Thanks in advance :)

ETA

I tried to adapt a piece of code I found, but it failed to work at all;

```
'What value do you want to find (must be in string form)?

fnd = 1

Set myRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("I:AC")
Set LastCell = Worksheets("Data").Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)

Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
     If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

  Loop

'Select Cells Containing Find Value
rng.Select

Exit Sub
```

Comment: You should show your code. No problem, it is right or not. Ok!!! If show, we can easily understand and can solve your problem quickly.

Comment: I've added a chunk of code I found to select all instances of Client 1 and tried to adapt it, but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. currently it create multiple sheets for each client. you should be able to change the behaviour if required, once you go through the code this is obvious

```
Sub MakeInvoiceSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, strStartCol As String, strEndCol As String, iStartRow As Integer, iEndRow As Integer
    Dim iClient As String, wsInv As Worksheet, strCompletedClients As String

    iStartRow = 1
    iEndRow = 8
    strStartCol = "A"
    strEndCol = "B"

    Set ws = Sheets("Client")
    strCompletedClients = ","

    For irow = iStartRow + 1 To iEndRow
        iClient = ws.Range(strStartCol & irow).Text

        If InStr(1, strCompletedClients, "," & iClient & ",") <= 0 Then
            ws.Select
            ws.Range("$" & strStartCol & "$" & iStartRow & ":$" & strEndCol & "$" & iEndRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & iClient
            ws.Range(strStartCol & iStartRow).Select
            ws.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Set wsInv = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            wsInv.Name = "Invoice For Client " & iClient
            wsInv.Paste
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
            strCompletedClients = strCompletedClients & iClient & ","
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Mr.Krishna, you should add some code comment in your answer. So, he can easily understand. Because he is beginner for VBA. Okay.!!

Comment: if you have edit functionality and you are not a beginner, be constructive and start doing it. easy to give easy advises.OK.!!